# AUC of Propensity Score Matching in R

Tags: r, auc, propensity-score-matching

Here is how I do propensity score matching in R:

```
m.out <- matchit(treat ~ x1+x2, data = Newdata, method = "subclass", subclass=6)
dta_m <- match.data(m.out)
propensity <- glm.nb(y ~ treat+x1+x2+treat:x1+treat:x2,data=dta_m)
summary(propensity)
```

Thereinto,"treat" is a dummy variable.

I want to see the accuracy of matching function (matchit), Hence I want to get Area under the ROC curve. My question is how to get AUC in PSM?
Thank you.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if someone could suggest any packages in R to solve  a similar question

Answer (score 2):

You should not do this. See my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/455027/why-dont-people-report-the-accuracy-ppv-or-npv-of-their-propensity-score-mode/). Several studies have shown that there is no correspondence between the AUC of a propensity score model (aka the C-statistic) and its performance. That said, the propensity scores are stored in the `distance` component of the `matchit` output object, so you can take those and the treatment vector and put them into a function that computes the AUC from these values. I don't know of a function to do this because, as I mentioned, it's not good practice to do this with propensity scores.